# smooth scroll to name

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have seen some standard code for smooth scroll to a href with # but I am doing a link to anchor by way of `name` attribute. So the code would be like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#on-water">On Water</a>
  </li>
```

goes to the section:

```
<a class="mwm-aal-item" name="on-water"></a>
```

It is a plugin called Better Anchor Links for wordpress, that is why it is set up that way.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2txszd46/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > a').on('click', function(){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('.mwm-aal-item').offset().top},3000);
    });
});
```

the previous example if you run the code for a specific anchor ..
 -

but if you want to run that with all anchors
 use this [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2txszd46/16/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('li > a').on('click', function(){
            var GetaName = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : $('a[name ='+GetaName[1]+']').offset().top},1000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you would like to achieve this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ywt5a6dn/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {  
        var target = $(this.hash);  
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('a[name="' + this.hash.substr(1) + '"]');  
        if (target.length == 0) target = $('html');  
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top }, 700);  
        return false;  
    });  
});
```